# Вертикальный вывод

Tags: c, d

Допустим мне нужно вывести таблицу 500 на 500 клеток, размер одной клетки 2х1, 
пишем функцию вывода(упрощенно):

```
void mapPrint() {
    int column, row;
    for (column = -1; column < MAPSIZE; ++column) {
        if (column == -1) {
            write("   ");
            for (int t = column + 1; t < MAPSIZE; t++)
                writef("%02d", t + 1);
            writeln();
            ++column;
        }
        for (row = -1; row < MAPSIZE; ++row) {

            if (row == -1) {
                writef("%03d", column);
                ++row;
            }
            if      (worldMap[column][row].localityType == "desert")
                    write(COLORDESERT,'D',' ',DEFAULT);
            else if (worldMap[column][row].localityType == "bank")
                    write(COLORBANK,'B',' ',DEFAULT);
            else (worldMap[column][row].localityType == "shoal")
                    write(COLORSHOAL,'S',' ',DEFAULT);
            }
            writeln();
    }
    write(DEFAULT);
}
```

Выводит:

```
   01020304050607080910
000D D S S W W W W W W 
001D D S S W W W W W W 
002D B S S S W W W W S 
003P B S S S W W W S S 
004P B B S S S W W S S 
005P P B B S S S S S S 
006P P P B B S S S S S 
007P P F B B B B B B B 
008M F F F F F F B B B 
009M M F F F F F F B B
```

Надо:

```
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   и
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1   т.
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0   д.
000D D S S W W W W W W 
001D D S S W W W W W W 
002D B S S S W W W W S 
003P B S S S W W W S S 
004P B B S S S W W S S 
005P P B B S S S S S S 
006P P P B B S S S S S 
007P P F B B B B B B B 
008M F F F F F F B B B 
009M M F F F F F F B B
```

Все нормально, пока количество колонок таблицы меньше 101, но когда **x** становится больше 100, цифры, указывающие на номер столбца, съезжают =\

Помогите, как выводить вертикально? По разрядам?

Кусок текста написан на Ди, примеры на Си принимаются.

**Отлично, вот вся функция, если кому надо...**

```
void mapPrint() {

    int column, row;

    for (column = -1; column < MAPSIZE; ++column) {
        if (column == -1) {

            write("   ");
            for (int t = column + 1; t < MAPSIZE; t++)
                writef("%d ", ((t%1000)/100));
            writeln();

            write("   ");
            for (int t = column + 1; t < MAPSIZE; t++)
                writef("%d ", ((t%100)/10));
            writeln();

            write("   ");
            for (int t = column + 1; t < MAPSIZE; t++)
                writef("%d ", (t%10));
            writeln();

            ++column;
        }

        for (row = -1; row < MAPSIZE; ++row) {

            if (row == -1) {
                writef("%03d", column);
                ++row;
            }

            if      (worldMap[column][row].localityType == "desert")
                    write(COLORDESERT,'D',' ',DEFAULT);
            else if (worldMap[column][row].localityType == "bank")
                    write(COLORBANK,'B',' ',DEFAULT);
            else if (worldMap[column][row].localityType == "forest")
                    write(COLORFOREST,'F',' ',DEFAULT);
            else if (worldMap[column][row].localityType == "mountains")
                    write(COLORMOUNTAINS,'M',' ',DEFAULT);
            else if (worldMap[column][row].localityType == "plain")
                    write(COLORPLAIN,'P',' ',DEFAULT);
            else if (worldMap[column][row].localityType == "water")
                    write(COLORWATER,'W',' ',DEFAULT);
            else if (worldMap[column][row].localityType == "shoal")
                    write(COLORSHOAL,'S',' ',DEFAULT);
        }
        writeln();
    }
    write(DEFAULT);
}
```

Выводит такое:

```
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
000D D S S W W W W W W 
001D D S S W W W W W W 
002D B S S S W W W W S 
003P B S S S W W W S S 
004P B B S S S W W S S 
005P P B B S S S S S S 
006P P P B B S S S S S 
007P P F B B B B B B B 
008M F F F F F F B B B 
009M M F F F F F F B B
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Используйте символ табуляции при выводе столбиков '\t'
2. Используйте спецификаторы формата при вызове функции вывода текста на экран printf.

Годится такое:

```
printf("%.3i",x); // выведет "001", "002", "003"....
printf("%3i",x); // выведет "  1", "  2", "  3"....
```

**Добавлено.**

Тогда лучше вынести отдельно подпрограмму вывода шапки таблицы. Получится что-то в духе:

```
for (i = 1; i <= col; i++)
    printf("%i ", (i%1000)/100);
printf("\n");
for (i = 1; i <= col; i++)
    printf("%i ", (i%100)/10);
printf("\n");
for (i = 1; i <= col; i++)
    printf("%i ", i%10);
printf("\n");
```

В принципе, никто не мешает обобщить на случай N разрядов.

Либо еще вариант: изменить таблицу - растянуть строки. Получится:

```
     01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
000   D  D  S  S  W  W  W  W  W  W 
001   D  D  S  S  W  W  W  W  W  W 
002   D  B  S  S  S  W  W  W  W  S 
003   P  B  S  S  S  W  W  W  S  S 
004   P  B  B  S  S  S  W  W  S  S 
005   P  P  B  B  S  S  S  S  S  S 
006   P  P  P  B  B  S  S  S  S  S 
007   P  P  F  B  B  B  B  B  B  B 
008   M  F  F  F  F  F  F  B  B  B 
009   M  M  F  F  F  F  F  F  B  B
```